# Как скопировать текстовый объект на многих строках в vim

Tags: vim

Предположим есть текст

```
- 'autoindent' is set by default
- 'autoread' is set by default
- 'backspace' defaults to "indent,eol,start"
- 'backupdir' defaults to .,~/.local/share/nvim/backup (|xdg|)
- 'complete' doesn't include "i"
- 'directory' defaults to ~/.local/share/nvim/swap// (|xdg|), auto-created
```

Как скопировать `autoindent autoread backspace...` и так далее в системный регистр?

П.С. пробовал vim-multiple-cursors, но этот [плагин глюченый](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors/issues/212) и позволяет копировать-вставлять только если не выходишь из режима multiple-cursors

Comment: Вам нужно скопировать несколько строк целиком? или прямоугольный блок, который содержит именно указанные вами слова?

Comment: @cronfy мне нужно скопировать слова в ординарных скобках, предполагаю, что это делается с помощью visual block

Comment: Посмотрите, это подойдет? http://superuser.com/q/208852/576308

Comment: @cronfy нет, так как все слова разного размера (переименовал вопрос)

Comment: @cronfy , к примеру здесь мне дали такой ответ  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149337/vim-way-to-yank-text-object-on-multiple-lines?noredirect=1#comment69503888_41149337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Скопировать несколько строк целиком

1. Перемещаемся на первую строку.
2. `V`
3. Перемещаем курсор на последнюю строку.
4. `y`

Текст в буфере. Вставить можно с помощью `P`.

## Скопировать и вставить прямоугольный блок

1. Перемещаемся на левый верхний угол.
2. `Ctrl-v` (в Windows `Ctrl-q`).
3. Перемещаем курсор на правый нижний угол.
4. `y`

Текст в буфере. Есть два варианта вставки:

1. Без новых строк - текст вставится в колонке, где находится курсор, отодвигая имеющийся текст вправо - команда `P`.
2. Создавая новые строки для текста из буфера - команда `:put`.

## Скопировать в один буфер множественные вхождения текста, подходящие по регулярному выражению

Если нужно скопировать нечто не прямоугольное, можно использовать копирование в регистр через регулярные выражения.

1. `qaq` - очищаем регистр "a".
2. `:%s/\v^- '([^']*)'/\=setreg('A', submatch(1), 'V')/n` (регулярка для конкретно вашего случая, что здесь происходит - см. объяснение ниже).

Текст в регистре "a". Вставить можно с помощью `P`. В вашем случае получается такой результат:

```
autoindent
autoread
backspace
backupdir
complete
directory
```

Что происходит в регулярке:

- \v - включение режима 'very magic', [чтобы работали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623160/can-i-turn-on-extended-regular-expressions-support-in-vim) расширенные регулярные выражения (в нашем случае нужны круглые скобки).
- Та часть, которую нужно добавить в буфер, заключена в круглые скобки.
- `setreg()` с помощью `submatch(1)` получает значение вхождения в круглых скобках и добавляет его в регистр "a" (обратите внимание, регистр указан заглавной буквой, чтобы текст именно добавился, а не заменил существующий).
- /n - указание s/// не производить замену текста.

Больше вариантов [здесь](https://superuser.com/a/818607/576308).

## Вручную набрать части текста в буфер

Если регулярным выражением собрать текст нет возможности, можно набрать его в буфер вручную:

1. `qaq` - очищаем регистр "a".
2. Выделяем нужный кусочек текста. Например, находясь на слове 'autoindent' нажимаем `vi'`, буквально такая команда означает "выделить слово внутри одинарных кавычек".
3. `"Ay` - копирует выделенный текст в регистр "a", добавляя в буфер, а не перезаписывая его.
4. Повторить пункты 2-3 сколько нужно раз.

Текст в буфере. Вставить можно с помощью `P`.

## Комбинация разных подходов

Собственно, если не набирать `qaq` перед каждым новым поиском, регистр не будет очищаться. Можно набрать в него данные сначала вручную, потом регуляркой, потом еще как-нибудь, потом опять вручную и т. д.

Comment: Как раз таки не оверкилл, а тот самый vim way
Я понял 2 вещи: vim-multiple-cursors нужный плагин и если они его не исправят - перейду на vintageous
Cпасибо

Comment: @BjornMelgaard обновил ответ, добавил пример регулярки для вашего случая и еще один вариант (ручной набор в буфер для случаев, когда регулярка не справляется).

Answer (score 1):

условие «получить текст между первой и второй кавычками» легко выполнить с помощью программы `cut`:

```
$ echo "- 'autoindent' is set by default" | cut -d "'" -f 2
autoindent
```

#### более длинный путь

в *vim*-е передать текущие выделенные строки внешней программе (в качестве которой мы будем использовать `cut`) можно с помощью конструкции:

```
:диапазон! внешняя-программа-или-команда
```

---

т.е., выделяете нужные строки в визуальном режиме, перейдя в него нажатием <kbd>V</kbd>, затем нажимаете <kbd>!</kbd> и в командной строке *vim*-а получаете такой текст:

```
:'<,'>!
```

после него вписываете внешнюю команду, чтобы получилось так:

```
:'<,'>! cut -d "'" -f 2
```

нажимаете `enter` и вместо всех выделенных строк получаете только слова между первой и второй кавычками:

```
autoindent
autoread
backspace
backupdir
complete
directory
```

нажимаете <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, чтобы повторить выделение того же диапазона строк, затем <kbd>y</kbd>, чтобы сохранить их в регистре (по умолчанию — в безымянном регистре `"`).

чтобы вернуть после этого исходное содержимое строк, нажмите <kbd>u</kbd>.

---

если надо работать не с диапазоном строк, а со всеми строками файла, то вся процедура будет чуть короче. выполняете команду:

```
:%! cut -d "'" -f 2
```

затем копируете все получившиеся строки в регистр (по умолчанию — в безымянный):

```
:%y
```

затем возвращаете исходные строки, нажав <kbd>u</kbd>.

---

#### более короткий путь

1. копируете нужные строки в безымянный регистр (т.е., выделяете их и нажимаете <kbd>y</kbd>).
2. вызываете программу `cut` с помощью функции `system()`, передавая ей содержимое безымянного регистра (`@"`), а её вывод записываете обратно в тот же регистр:

   ```
   :let @"=system("cut -d \"'\" -f 2",@")
   ```

   кавычки внутри параметров для программы `cut` пришлось «забэкслэшить».
3. теперь в безымянном регистре содержатся искомые строки. можно их вставить в нужное место, например, нажав <kbd>p</kbd>.

естественно, можно использовать и любой другой регистр. сохранение строк в регистр `a`: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>. адресация регистра `a` в командной строке: `@a` (вместо `@"`). вставить из регистра `a`: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: Стоит запомнить такой ответ. Проводим разбор лучшего варианта и узнаем, почему [vim-multiple-cursors не работает](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149337/vim-way-to-yank-text-object-on-multiple-lines/41151879#41152180)

Comment: @BjornMelgaard, придумал более короткий путь (и дополнил ответ).

Comment: вау, можно даже сразу указать регистр +

Comment: регистр можно было указать и в первом варианте: `:%ya` — скопировать все строки в регистр `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Решил перейти на Vintageous. [Мои конфиги здесь](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/master/User)

Также подключил MarkAndMove, AceJump и Surround.

Просто посмотрите, что такое MarkAndMove и оцените потенциал. Это намного лучше vim